# VBA Word Shape location - top left corner

Tags: vba, ms-word, qr-code, shapes

I have written a small function, based on example provided by producer of Stroke Scribe ActiveX object. This is an plugin which allows us to create in Microsoft Word by VBA Macro an QR Code object.

The problem is with setting up a shape location

```
shp.Left = 0 + LeftMargin
shp.Top = 0 + TopMargin
```

I would like to put this shape (QR Code) on specific page on the most left top corner. But sometimes shape jumps to previous page (on bottom) or other location (vertical center).

Can you help me recognize a problem and fix it to locate Shape Object every time top left corner?

Code:

```
Sub QRCodeGenerator(SOP, BookmarkID, Page, TopMargin, LeftMargin)
Dim doc As Document
Set doc = Application.ActiveDocument



For Each sh In doc.Shapes
  If sh.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
    If sh.OLEFormat.ProgID = "STROKESCRIBE.StrokeScribeCtrl.1" Then
      sh.Delete
    End If
  End If
Next

With doc.PageSetup
   usable_w = .PageWidth
   usable_h = .PageHeight
End With

Dim pg As Range
Set pg = doc.GoTo(wdGoToPage, wdGoToRelative, Page)

Dim shp As Shape
Set shp = doc.Shapes.AddOLEControl(ClassType:="STROKESCRIBE.StrokeScribeCtrl.1", Anchor:=pg)

Dim sMyString As String
sMyString = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(BookmarkID).Range.Text
sMyString = Replace(sMyString, "FORMTEXT ", "")

shp.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
shp.Height = InchesToPoints(0.6)
shp.Width = shp.Height
shp.Left = 0 + LeftMargin
shp.Top = 0 + TopMargin ' // usable_h - shp.Height * 3 + TopMargin

Dim ss As StrokeScribe
Set ss = shp.OLEFormat.Object

ss.Alphabet = QRCODE 'StrokeScribe will draw a QR code picture
ss.Text = SOP & ";" & sMyString 'Any text you want to encode in the barcode
ss.QrECL = H  'Changes the default error correction level. This can be omitted
ss.QrMinVersion = 3 'Specifies the minimum barcode size. This can be omitted
ss.FontColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
' ss.UTF8 = True 'Enable this, if you want to encode national characters for smartphones
If ss.Error Then
   MsgBox ss.ErrorDescription
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: 1. `shp.Top = usable_h - shp.Height * 3 + TopMargin` rather positions the barcode on the bottom part of the page. What if you change it to `shp.Top = shp.Height * 3 + TopMargin` ?
2. Is there any position where you can steadily glue the barcode or it jumps away from other locations, too?

Comment: Hi AcsErno, Thanks for comment. That `shp.Top = usable_h - shp.Height * 3 + TopMargin` was my "test" formula to put object on the bottom of page, but still doesnt work :/

Comment: The thing to bear in mind is that a "page" doesn't really exist in Word. Pages are created on the fly. Change the document and pagination also changes. By defining the location of your shape `RelativeToPage` you undertake to provide a stable document where "pages" don't change. In other words, your problem may well go away once you are done testing and introduce no more changes to the rest of the document. On the other hand, consider anchoring your shape relative to a paragraph, which is much easier to control, or even make it an InlineShape.

Answer (score 2):

Word SHAPE objects must be anchored to a Range. The page location of that Range determines on which page the Shape will display. There's nothing you can do to "lock" a Shape to a particular page.

That said, it is possible to dictate that a Shape always appears in the same location on whichever page the anchoring Range lies.

This is always tricky if you add such a Shape before document editing is finished, because editing can move the anchoring paragraph to a different page. It can help to choose a paragraph as the anchor that's unlikely to move, for example perhaps the first paragraph on the page.

Something I did once, long ago, was write a macro that checks the page locations of Shapes before printing or saving. When inserting and positioning the Shape, I give it a Name that includes the page number. Before printing/saving the macro checks the page number in the Shape name with the page on which the Shape is located. If the two don't match, CUT the Shape and PASTE it to a paragraph on the correct page (it remembers its position settings).

The code sample below demonstrates how to name the Shape, lock the anchor to a specific paragraph and position the Shape flush to the top, left corner of the page.

```
Sub ShapePosTopLeft()
    Dim doc As word.Document
    Dim shp As word.Shape
    Dim rng As word.Range

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set rng = doc.GoTo(wdGoToPage, wdGoToRelative, Page)
    Set rng = rng.Paragraphs(1).Range
    Set shp = doc.Shapes.AddOLEControl(ClassType:="STROKESCRIBE.StrokeScribeCtrl.1", Anchor:=rng)


    With shp
        .Name = "Shape_Page" & Page
        .LockAnchor = True
        .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage
        .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
        .Left = 0
        .Top = 0
    End With
End Sub
```